# Having a List of the same object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am designing a code-fire migration using Entity Framework and have some problem when one object has a List of the same type as itself. Say I have a `User` object which has a `List<User>` as its `Friends`:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    // some other stuff

    public List<User> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is EF looks for a foreign key for the User and tries to create one when it couldn't find any:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "User_UserId", c => c.Int());
```

I am trying to avoid making `UserId` a key and foreign key at the same time, so what's a good practice here?

Comment: `UserId` can't be a foreign key, it's a one-to-many relationship. You'll need a separate friend-of-user table, with entries connecting user id to its friend ids.

Comment: You need to have separate tables for both Friends and Users. In your case, Entity framework is trying to figure out the foreign key for to build  relationship. And it finds the UserId from same table which is unique primary key. You can not avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

A separate table would be best here.

Name: UserFriend
PK: UserFriendId
FK: UserId
FK: FriendId

Answer (score -2):

You can't use `List<T>` for a related collection in Entity Framework. It must be `virtual ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Tried the virtual ICollection and got the same result

Comment: This is not true. You can use `List<T>`. I don't say it's recommended, but it's possible. And it doesn't *have* to be virtual.